# Asp.net Website load test

Tags: asp.net, performance, testing

I watched old videos that suggest to test the asp.net website load using

```
Microsoft Web Application Stress Tool.
```

But there is a  broken link to get the download.

Can any body suggest me a tool to test website performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAST has been withdrawn in favour of  Visual Studio Team System Test Edition or the Capacity Analysis tool in the IIS Resource Kit.

The IIS Resource Kit is available at:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&DisplayLang=en

The WAST tool can still be downloaded from http://www.chizl.com/downloads/web_stress_tool_setup.exe but I don't know how long for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a video on it: http://www.asp.net/Learn/vsts-videos/video-157.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://fwptt.sourceforge.net - generates C# code on the fly which you can also customize - does not have out of the box support for non windows forms authentication